# Canvas rotation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

There is the following code for drawing image on canvas:

```
img.onload = () => {
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    let maxSideSize = 160;
    let sideDiff = img.width - img.height;
    let width = img.width;
    let height = img.height;
    let left = 0;
    let top = 0;

    if (sideDiff > 0) {
        left = sideDiff / 2;
        width = height;
    } else if (sideDiff < 0) {
        top = -sideDiff / 2;
        height = width;
    }

    canvas.width = maxSideSize;
    canvas.height = maxSideSize;

    //context.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    //context.rotate(Math.PI/2);
    context.drawImage(img, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, maxSideSize, maxSideSize);

    avatar = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
};

img.src = e.target.result;
```

As you can see I want to draw image on canvas with some resize. It works. But now I want to rotate image also. If I uncomment 'context.rotate(Math.PI/2)' line I'll see white square (avatar variable). How can I fix it? I think I need to use 'transform' method, but I don't understand how I must do it.

Comment: Most likely, rotate rotates around (0,0), which is the upper left corner. Therefore, you need to translate the whole image so that it's center is now in that corner, rotate it, and translate it back.

Comment: Can you provide me the code?

Comment: context.translate(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2); context.rotate(Math.PI/2); context.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2); (or first positive, then negative, depending on the coordinate system)

Comment: It works, but I don't understand why. Can you provide answer with details? I'll read and mark :)

Comment: Again, rotate(pi/2) rotates the whole image around the origin, (0,0). Your image is in the first quadrant of your coordinate system. If you rotate it by 90°, it is in another quadrant, which is outside of your canvas, therefore invisible. If you first move the image so that it's center is now the origin, you basically rotate it around the center, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
context.save();    
context.translate(objectCenterX, objectCenterY);
context.rotate(Math.PI/2);
context.drawImage(img, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, maxSideSize, maxSideSize);
context.translate(-objectCenterX, -objectCenterY);
context.restore();
```

I would also like to point out that this question has been answered a million times.  A quick google search would provide you with your answer

Comment: QBM5: You don't need to both `save / restore` and `untransform`. Since untransform is more efficient in this case, use untransform (first unrotate and then untransform) and remove `save / restore`. ;-) Also, are you intentionally rotating from the image's top-left ... rotating from image's center is more traditional?

Comment: I have run into many issue when you dont use save and restore.  For instance, even though the translation is set back to its source the rotation is not.  If not for save/restore every drawling after this one would have a rotation applied to it.  But that is just my experience in doing rotation.  Thanks for the input :)

Comment: QBM5: If you're having trouble undoing your transformations, just remember that you must always undo them in reverse order. So if you translate+rotate then you must unrotate+untranslate. Then you should have no problems :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I integrated the code in the [following tutorial](http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/), titled *Drawing rotated images into canvas*, at http://creativejs.com

**Note:** I used jQuery only to generate my query for the placeholder image. There is not jQuery involved in the transformation/drawing logic below.

```js
var context = document.getElementById('avatar').getContext('2d');
var avatar = null;

// Create a placeholder image at http://placehold.it.
var avatarUrl = createQueryUrl('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text', {
  txtsize  : 42,        // Font Size
  txt      : 'Foo Bar', // Text
  w        : 178,       // Image Width
  h        : 178,       // Image Height
  txttrack : 1,         // Text Spacing
  bg       : 'ddbb33',  // Background Color
  txtclr   : '000000'   // Forground Color
});

// Load the image and rotate it on the canvas.
var avatarImg = loadImage(context, avatarUrl, avatar);

// ================================================================
// ----------------- Do not modify the code below -----------------
// ================================================================
var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180;

// Uses jQuery's $.fn.param function.
function createQueryUrl(url, params) {
  return url + '?' + $.param(params);
}

function loadImage(context, imageUrl, imageData) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    // Rotate aroud the center of the image.
    var x = img.width / 2;
    var y = img.height / 2;

    // Rotate the image and draw it.
    drawRotatedImage(context, img, x, y, 90);
    
    // Store the image data.
    imageData = context.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  };

  img.src = imageUrl;
  return img;
}

function drawRotatedImage(context, image, x, y, angle) {
  var maxSideSize = 160;
  var sideDiff = avatarImg.width - avatarImg.height;
  var width = avatarImg.width;
  var height = avatarImg.height;
  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;

  if (sideDiff > 0) {
    left = sideDiff / 2;
    width = height;
  } else if (sideDiff < 0) {
    top = -sideDiff / 2;
    height = width;
  }

  context.canvas.width = maxSideSize;
  context.canvas.height = maxSideSize;

  // Save the current co-ordinate system before we modify it.
  context.save();

  // Move to the middle of where we want to draw our image.
  context.translate(x, y);

  // Rotate around that point, converting our angle from degrees to radians.
  context.rotate(angle * TO_RADIANS);

  // Draw it up and to the left by half the width and height of the image.
  context.drawImage(image, -(image.width / 2), -(image.height / 2));

  // Finally, restore the co-ords to how they were when we began.
  context.restore();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="avatar" width="178" height="178"></canvas>
```